# space issue with jquery masonry plugin not worked in IE and firefox

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-masonry

```
<div class="rectangle-wrapper">
        <div class="rectangle-3 rect-box">
            <div class="image-wrap">
                <img src="img source here" alt=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="controls">
                <i class="icon-arrow-up icon-2 icon-it"></i>

                <div class="text-3">69</div>
                <i class="icon-arrow-down icon-3 icon-it"></i>
                <a onclick="" href="#" class="btn-rect">
                    <div class="rectangle-4 rect-btn">
                        <div class="text-4">Sho Frenz</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <a onclick="" href="#"class="btn-rect">
                    <div class="rectangle-5 rect-btn">
                        <div class="text-5">Aii Waant!</div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

 $(".rectangle-wrapper").masonry({
                itemSelector:".rect-box ",
                columnWidth:240,
                isFitWidth:true,
                gutterWidth:0
            });
```

I have using masonry from http://masonry.desandro.com/ and found a problem that it's not work in firefox and IE.

it's show me as expect 4 elements in the single rows. In Firefox and Ie their is only 2 elements show on elemnts and other place is a spaces.

Can someone let me know how I can fix it.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing all your JS and CSS; do you have an online sandbox or jsfiddle one can look at with devtools?

Comment: I remove the columnwidth (from js as 240) and it's show me 3 now in fx and Ie. In chrome it's 4 . If I increase the width a little more then I am sure it's will work.

Comment: @Systembolaget look at this script http://ankit.webmatrix.arvixe.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at it in Chrome's devtools, you got it setup wrong. Masonry operates on elements within a container. Don't just put other things in there like headers and footers. You don't give the container a height and width - the width is determined by the viewer's browser window, the height by the number and size of elements. The basic setup is organised like this:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  <div class="item">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

The elements should ideally follow a module width and height wise, as you can see in the original documentation. Then you call Masonry like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('#container').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.item',
    columnWidth : 240
  });
});
```

It is all in the documentation [here](http://masonry.desandro.com/docs/intro.html).

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear what your means. I use rectangle-wrapper which contain .rect-box that I used as item (as your code). please clear me your point then I can go better with issue.

Comment: There is so much tangled code, plugins, scripts - and a separate class for every element instead of styling common element features with a class for these features... Why don't you start again, but simple first - learn about CSS, then implement only one plugin (Masonry), get it to work right, and then worry about all your design elements and buttons and extra plugins after the bare-bones structure of your website works? Otherwise, it is just too timeconsuming to find out where all the problems come from (conflicting scripts, conflicting plugins, conflicting CSS, ...).